# Writing a phone call scene in a screenplay

Tags: dialogue, formatting, screenwriting, scriptwriting

I’m writing a scene that is on a phone call.  I don't want to hear one person in a voiceover.  Instead, I want to cut back and forth between the two people speaking.

Do I have to use a new scene heading every time, and notate the fact that the camera is cutting back and forth between locations?

Comment: It's not really the same question, but these could help: https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/21142/how-do-i-write-a-news-broadcast-montage-in-different-locations-in-a-screenplay/21194#21194 and https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/32033/how-are-intercut-scenes-done

Answer (score 6):

No, do not use a new scene heading each time. Use [**INTERCUT**](http://www.screenwriting.info/15.php), described at the link.

Basically, a scene heading for each separate scene, then "intercut between X and Y [and Z and ...]. Then exposition or dialogue without new scene headings.

The following excerpt is cut and pasted from the link as an example; pardon any screenplay formatting errors.

> INT. SHERRI'S APARTMENT - NIGHT
>
> Sherri starts disrobing in front of her open bedroom window.
>
> INT. LENNY'S APARTMENT - NIGHT
>
> Lenny gets up to cross to the fridge to get a beer. He looks out his window and catches a glimpse of Sherri across the courtyard. He freezes, watching her.
>
> INTERCUT BETWEEN LENNY AND SHERRI
>
> Sherri sits on the bed and unbuttons her double-breasted suit jacket.
>
> Lenny moves closer to the window for a better vantage point.
>
> Sherri stands, hopping a few feet, trying to step out of her skirt.
>
> Lenny, eyes glued to Sherri, moves to keep her in view. He slams his bare foot into a dumbbell on the floor.

**Another example:**

> INT. LIVING ROOM - NIGHT
>
> Sherri, comfy on the couch, is reading a book when the phone rings. She answers it.
>
> ```
>                                     SHERRI
>
>                    Hello?
> ```
>
> EXT. PHONE BOOTH - REST AREA
>
> Lenny sips a Coke as he talks.
>
> ```
>                                     LENNY
>
>                    Hey Honey, I'm in Barstow.
> ```
>
> INTERCUT BETWEEN LENNY and SHERRI
>
> ```
>                                    SHERRI
>
>                    Oh, Honey, that's great...
>
>                    you'll be here by morning.
>
>                                    LENNY
>
>                    Yep... I've got the pedal to the
>
>                    metal.
> ```